# Mutually Independent Events and Expectation and SLLN Diverge

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Sorry I posted this question on a new account I created because I was not able to gain access to my main acct. I was able to get back on to my main acct.

I have been self studying probability using some Stanford lecture notes and am trying to see if my logic is correct for the following exercise:

$X_{i}$ are mutually independent with $P(X_n=n^2-1)=1-P(X_n=-1)=\frac{1}{n^2}$ then $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=0$ and

$n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ converges almost surely to -1. I figured since $P(X_n= -1)\rightarrow 1$ then $P(X_n= -1\hspace{3mm} a.a)=1$ More formally:

$$P(\cap_{n=1}\cup_{k\ge n}|X_n+1|>\epsilon)\le \sum_{k\ge n}P(|X_n+1|>\epsilon)$$

then taking the limit on both sides shows
$$P(\cap_{n=1}\cup_{k\ge n}|X_n+1|>\epsilon)=0$$
since $P(|X_n+1|>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ then once can conclude $X_n\rightarrow -1$ almost surely then the convergence of the sum follows. Does any of this make sense?

Comment: You would not get the same result with $P(X_n=n-1)=1-P(X_n=-1)=\frac{1}{n}$ so perhaps somewhere your proof should explicitly use the $n^2$

Comment: @Henry I can see where convergence in probability would not imply almost sure convergence so my first statement is wrong. Is my logic to the arguments beginning at "More formally" also wrong. I understand the proof presented below but I am trying to get better at writing proofs and would appreciate where my argument falls apart past the "More Formally" point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(|X_n+1| >\epsilon \to 0$ for every $\epsilon >0$ only tells you that $X_n \to -1$ in probability. How does this give a.s convergence?

Here is a simple argument using Borel-Cantelli Lemma:

$\sum P(X_n=n^{2}-1) <\infty$ so there is probability $0$ that $X_n=n^{2}-1$ for infinitely many $n$. This implies that $X_n=-1$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, with probability $1$. This in turn implies that $\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k \to -1$ a.s..

Comment: Side question If I am given $P(A_n)\rightarrow 0$ am I guaranteed that $P(A_n \hspace{2mm} i.o)=0$?

Comment: No. In fact if $A_n$'s are independent, $P(A_n) \to 0$ but $\sum P(A_n)=\infty$ then $P(A_n i.o. )=1$. @NoeVidales

Comment: One last question  I can see where convergence in probability would not imply almost sure convergence so my first statement is wrong. Is my logic to the arguments beginning at "More formally" also wrong. I understand the proof presented below but I am trying to get better at writing proofs and would appreciate where my argument falls apart past the "More Formally".

Comment: Examples where we have convergence in probability but not a s. convergence are standard. You can find them in almost any book on Probability Theory. In particular you can look at discussion of types of convergenec of r.v. 's in K L Chung's book A Course in Probability Theory. @NoeVidales

Comment: I am able to understand proofs after the fact, but find it difficult to develop the intuition to create my own proofs. It feels like a lot of memorization. Do you have any advice for someone trying to get better at proofs and developing the intuition?